# You must supply a layout_width attribute in some devices

Tags: android, layout

I am experiencing this problem in my app and I can't seem to understand how it happen. It only occurs in Samsung Galaxy Y phone, I tried this code in other devices and it is ok.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jpac.remaster.gtc/jpac.remaster.gtc.GTCSplash}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #7: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1658)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #7: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:3598)
at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:3678)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:1169)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:998)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:74)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:625)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
at jpac.remaster.gtc.GTCSplash.onCreate(GTCSplash.java:33)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
... 11 more
```

Can anyone help me with this? btw, here is the xml in question:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/tuna" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dev_logo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/speech_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/badge_height"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_dark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also the activity for this xml file is the main entry point of the app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have the same layout and dimensions for all dpi?

Comment: Yeah, it feels like that `@dimen/speech_height` perhaps is unavailable in some situations.

Comment: oh. I see, I think I'm getting it now. By the way, is Galaxy Y a small screen device? probably that's the problem cause I don't have a dimensions.xml for value-small

Comment: @kishidp did you discover the mail issue that did cause that?

Answer (score 2):

If you have dimensions (or any other values or resources) specified for particular densities or screen sizes, make sure you also have them defined in the generic directory (i.e. "values", "drawable")